# convert the time to a specific format

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have the current time format returned from the web service:

```
2012-06-25T23:45:52.664Z
```

I want to get something like:

```
   2012 june 25 23:45
```

So without seconds and the Z format indicator.

My relevant code is:

```
myConvertedTime = [[myActualTime dateFromString] stringFromDate];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `NSDateFormatter` object. And rather than specify a format yourself, it's best to let the framework pick the one that suits based on the user's internationalization settings. This is done as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
myConvertedTime = [formatter stringForObjectValue:[myActualTime dateFromString]];
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 2):

try these

NSDate *dateTemp = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy MMM dd hh:mm"];

dateTemp = [dateFormat1 dateFromString:newInvoice.date];

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy MMMM  dd HH:mm"];
NSString *myConvertedTime = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"];
 NSString *dateString = @"2012-06-25T23:45:52.664Z";
dateString = [dateString substringToIndex:[dateString length]-5];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy MMMM dd HH:mm"]; 
NSString *dateText = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormatter2 release];
NSLog(@"the date is:%@",dateText);
```